# Angular 2 material tabs - content loading on tab active only

Tags: angular, material-design

Just a simple question.
I want to implement Angular 2 Material Tabs in a way that each tab content it is initialized only when the corresponding tab is set to active.

This is what I use.
https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I've done this, and works for me

```
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {
  private tabs = {
    selectedIndex: 0
  };
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData(0);
  }

  selectChange($event: MdTabChangeEvent) {
    this.getData($event.index);
  }

  getData(index) {
    Observable
     .create(observer => setTimeout(() => observer.next(index), 0))
     .subscribe(index => {
      this.tabs[index] = true;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Raul, is there a github code that you have for this implementation ? I really need this but need more information or see a demo. If you could provide a link please.

Thanks

Comment: Maddy, I no longer have the code, and there is a better implementation to this.    Have you tried passing the tabs in the URL ? Or is not suitable for you ?